# jQuery DataTable PDF export table cells has no borders

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, datatables

I'm using jQuery DataTable to display a table. This table includes a "PDF Export" button. The export displays a PDF form but this form has no borders around the cells. It's just a text form (versus a table like Excel).
I want something like:  for each cell but I can't seem to find a way to do this. Can anyone help?
My javascript code to set up this DataTable looks like the following:

```
$("table[id$='jQueryDataTable']").dataTable(
            {
                aLengthMenu: [
                    [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, -1],
                    [10, 25, 50, 100, 200, "All"]
                ],
                iDisplayLength: -1,
                dom: 'Blrftip',
                buttons: [
                    {
                        extend: 'pdf',
                        title: 'Non Desctructive Inspection ' +
                            '   DATE: ' + d,
                        pageSize: 'A2',
                        orentation: 'landscape',
                        exportOptions: {  // This is IMPORTANT --- Monty
                            orthogonal: 'sort'
                        }//,
                        //function(){}
                    }
                ],
                aoColumnDefs: [{
                    "aTargets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    "defaultContent": "",
                    "ordering": true
                }
```

});

Thanks in advance.
Steve

Comment: can you add your the JSON you are using for the table data and the HTML markup (initial not generated)?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to customize function:

```
var objLayout = {};
objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .8; };
objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .5; };
objLayout['hLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
objLayout['vLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function(i) { return 8; };
objLayout['paddingRight'] = function(i) { return 8; };
doc.content[0].layout = objLayout;
```

Complete datatable implementation is:

```
$('#datatable').DataTable({
        lengthMenu: [
            [4, 7, 10, 15, 20, -1],
            [4, 7, 10, 15, 20, "Todo"]
        ],
        responsive: true,
        paging: true,
        pagingType: "full_numbers",
        stateSave: true,
        processing: true,
        dom: 'Blftirp',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-files-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'Copy',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'PDF',
                extension: ".pdf",
                filename: "name",
                title: "",
                orientation: 'landscape',
                customize: function (doc) {

                    doc.styles.tableHeader = {
                        color: 'black',
                        background: 'grey',
                        alignment: 'center'
                    }

                    doc.styles = {
                        subheader: {
                            fontSize: 10,
                            bold: true,
                            color: 'black'
                        },
                        tableHeader: {
                            bold: true,
                            fontSize: 10.5,
                            color: 'black'
                        },
                        lastLine: {
                            bold: true,
                            fontSize: 11,
                            color: 'blue'
                        },
                        defaultStyle: {
                            fontSize: 10,
                            color: 'black'
                        }
                    }

                    var objLayout = {};
                    objLayout['hLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .8; };
                    objLayout['vLineWidth'] = function(i) { return .5; };
                    objLayout['hLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['vLineColor'] = function(i) { return '#aaa'; };
                    objLayout['paddingLeft'] = function(i) { return 8; };
                    objLayout['paddingRight'] = function(i) { return 8; };
                    doc.content[0].layout = objLayout;

                    // margin: [left, top, right, bottom]

                    doc.content.splice(0, 0, {
                        text: [
                            {text: 'Texto 0', italics: true, fontSize: 12}
                        ],
                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                        alignment: 'center'
                    });

                    doc.content.splice(0, 0, {

                        table: {
                            widths: [300, '*', '*'],
                            body: [
                                [
                                    {text: 'Texto 1', bold: true, fontSize: 10}
                                    , {text: 'Texto 2', bold: true, fontSize: 10}
                                    , {text: 'Texto 3', bold: true, fontSize: 10}]
                            ]
                        },

                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 12],
                        alignment: 'center'
                    });


                    doc.content.splice(0, 0, {

                        table: {
                            widths: [300, '*'],
                            body: [
                                [
                                    {
                                        text: [
                                            {text: 'Texto 4', fontSize: 10},
                                            {
                                                text: 'Texto 5',
                                                bold: true,
                                                fontSize: 10
                                            }

                                        ]
                                    }
                                    , {
                                    text: [
                                        {
                                            text: 'Texto 6',
                                            bold: true, fontSize: 18
                                        },
                                        {
                                            text: 'Texto 7',
                                            fontSize: 10
                                        }

                                    ]
                                }]
                            ]
                        },

                        margin: [0, 0, 0, 22],
                        alignment: 'center'
                    });


                },
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-file-excel-o"></i>',
                titleAttr: 'CSV',
                fieldSeparator: ';',
                fieldBoundary: '"',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible'
                }
            },

            {
                extend: 'print',
                text: '<i class="fa fa-print"></i>',
                exportOptions: {
                    columns: ':visible',
                }
            },

            {
                extend: 'colvis',
                postfixButtons: ['colvisRestore'],
                collectionLayout: 'fixed four-column'
            }

        ]

    });
```